# willHideViewController not called when switching to view in portrait mode

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, uisplitviewcontroller

My iPad app uses the standard UISplitViewController. My problem is, if I

- Rotate to portrait, I put a Popover button for the Master list - Fine
- Select an item via the popover, that changes the detailview (This uses a `prepareForSegue` which sets `self.splitViewController.delegate = newViewDetailViewController;`
- The resulting detailview is now missing a popoverbutton. If I rotate to landscape, the master list appears. If I then again rotate to portrait, a popoverbutton appears.

So - How can I ensure `willHideViewController` will be called on `viewDidLoad`, for example?
I can detect what the orientation is, but I still need the barbuttonitem and popovercontroller needed in

`- (void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController *)splitController willHideViewController:(UIViewController *)viewController withBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem forPopoverController:(UIPopoverController *)popoverController`

For now I am following Apples MultipleDetailView example as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7885625/ios-uisplitviewcontrollers-popover-controller-button-disappear-after-pushing-ne).

But since I am having multiple MasterControllers as well, it's a real hassle to store (a static) pointer to the popoverbutton item and setting it every time I push a level on my masterview controller.

Hopefully, someone has a good way of solving this problem :-)

Comment: I'm having this same issue, did you ever get it figured out?

Comment: I ended using the example I linked to from Apple. It wasn't an issue with multiple mastercontrollers, since I realized that the popoverbutton gets delivered to me in the `willHideViewController` method. 

So, I have a `SubstitutableDetailViewController` protocol that my detail views implement.

Comment: I'm having the same problem, and I'm using the same Apple sample code that uses the `SubstitutableDetailViewController` protocol. It doesn't receive `(void)splitViewController:(UISplitViewController*)svc willShowViewController:(UIViewController *)aViewController invalidatingBarButtonItem:(UIBarButtonItem *)barButtonItem`  when the view controller was loaded before and rotated when it was not visible.

Answer (score 3):

I ran into the same problem and finally figured out what was missing.  There is a little code in the AppDelegate to performs some initialization.  It is in the didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method.  Here is the code that goes in there:

```
UISplitViewController *splitViewController = (UISplitViewController *)self.window.rootViewController;
UINavigationController *navigationController = [splitViewController.viewControllers lastObject];
splitViewController.delegate = (id)navigationController.topViewController;
```

They're all important to operate the split view controller, but the last line is the most line for getting the method to fire is the last one.  I am building a universal application and this was missing.  To ensure that it didn't affect my iPhone side I wrapped it in a UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM check.

Comment: wrapping it in the UI user interface idiom check matches what happens in the generated AppDelegate.m code when a master-detail app is generated via template in Xcode.  if you don't do this, the attempt to send a message to @selector viewControllers would crash your app.